# Calling EJB through java

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-2.x

I have no knowledge of EJB. I am asssuming its an alternative to get data from somewhere as we do in consuming webservices. For my new project we will be using EJB for getting data. These services will be developed by some other team.

I was hoping if someone can guide me to links on how to use EJB services in our java code. What all things are needed.
Like for consuming webservice, we have a wsdl, generate client, create stub object and call our method. Similar kind of steps for consuming ejb servies.

Comment: Have you tried the [Java EE 6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/)?

Comment: yes, others too, it was basically how to create a EJB services. I am continuing on that, but was hoping to get guidance on consuming it, and the things required

Comment: What do you mean by consuming? Inject your EJBs with `@EJB` annotations and call their methods to do the required job.

Comment: To be honest, i am completely new to EJB concept: I will try explaing my requirement with webservice example. As in webservice, we only need the wsdl and the endpoint url where it is deploy. We do not need to know how it was build, except the protocol it uses. Then we just generate client (apache axis), create stub object (using endpoint url) and call our methods. Rest complete is abstract to us.

Similar kind of things in EJB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For EJBs you don't need to create a client.
Just "inject" it inside you code.

If you want to call it from EE code (e.g. other EJB or a servlet) just use @EJB to define the EJB injection.

If you want to use it in not EE code (e.g. Struts action) you use JNDI to lookup for the EJB.

Comment: Thanks, i needed correct keywords to google. :)

Comment: That was the idea of my answer. You're welcome.